# IronPython Event in C# when Python socket receives data

Tags: c#, python

I have this code in my python project:

```
def Receive():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
        data = data.decode()
        print("(Python) => " + currentData)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

If it receives something, it prints out the message, is there any way to call a method in C# when the socket receives stuff?

Comment: You mean a windows/c# version of `select` type functionality?

Comment: What do you mean with this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to call some code written in C# from python script which you are running using IronPython. Easiest way is to add reference to your assembly and call some static method directly from python.

**Python side**

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("YourAssembly")

from MyNameSpace import MyClass

def Receive():
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
            data = data.decode()
            print("(Python) => " + currentData)
            time.sleep(0.1)

            # Calling C# handler.
            MyClass.DoSomething()
```

**C# side**

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public static class MyClass {
        public static void DoSomething() {
            Debug.Print("Doing something...")
        }
    }
}
```